# Litespeed external application max connection change

Tags: next.js, configuration, litespeed, dedicated-server

On my dedicated server, I run Nextjs(frontend) and PHP(backend).
Nextjs runs on port 8080 and uses server PHP APIs. Every things worked fine until my user number achieves to 200. At this number of users Nextjs gets timeout from APIs (Instead APIs work very good). So, it observed that maybe **LiteSpeed** limited max connection
.

[LiteSpeed monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0UU6.png)

As you can see the max connection is limited to 200.

I changed Home>Tuning>"Max Connections" to 500;

[Max connection settings in LiteSpeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUkdb.png)

Added web-server in "External Applications", but nothing changed.
Thanks

[External Application in LiteSpeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16DBS.png)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The External Application **MAX Connection** can be set from the Web Console > Server > External App > Max Connections. Specifies the maximum number of concurrent connections that can be established between the server and an external application.

The real-time state will display doable the number you have set from the above setting. So, if I set 2000 to the Max Connections, then the stats will display with 4000.

In order to check the settings are applied, please check the content of **/tmp/lshttpd/.rtreport**. You should see an entry like `EXTAPP [Proxy] [] [proxy]: CMAXCONN: 2000, EMAXCONN: 2000` ..etc.

If it still shows incorrect numbers, please contact LiteSpeed support.